# File existence check after a folder rename returns an incorrect value on UNC share

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, file-io

On a Windows 7 (or server) box, we have a folder on a UNC share (cross machine UNC, *not* localhost). We rename that folder, and then check for the existence of a file at the new folder location. Even though it exists, it takes almost 5 seconds for File.Exists to return true on it.

Full repro can be found on https://github.com/davidebbo/NpmFolderRenameIssue. Here is the core code:

```
// This file doesn't exist yet
// Note that the presence of this existence check is what triggers the bug below!!
Console.WriteLine("Exists (should be false): " + File.Exists("test/test2/myfile"));

// Create a directory, with a file in it
Directory.CreateDirectory("test/subdir/test");
File.WriteAllText("test/subdir/test/myfile", "Hello");

// Rename the directory
Directory.Move("test/subdir/test", "test/test2");

var start = DateTime.UtcNow;

// List the files at the new location. Here, our file shows up fine
foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles("test/test2"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}

for (; ; )
{
    // Now do a simple existence test. It should also be true, but when
    // running on a (cross machine) UNC share, it takes almost 5 seconds to become true!
    if (File.Exists("test/test2/myfile")) break;

    Console.WriteLine("After {0} milliseconds, test/test2/myfile doesn't show as existing",
        (DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalMilliseconds);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

Console.WriteLine("After {0} milliseconds, test/test2/myfile correctly shows as existing!",
    (DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalMilliseconds);
```

So it seems like the initial existence check causes the existence value to be cached, causing this bogus behavior.

**Questions**: what is the explanation for this? What's the best way to avoid it?

**NOTE**: this issue initially arose when using npm (Node Package Manager) on Windows. The code I have here is a C# port of the repro. See https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2230 for the original Node/npm issue. The goal is to find a way to address it.

Comment: Do note that calling `File.Exists` won't solve possible race conditions. I'm not sure if it's even necessary here. Whatever you're doing in response to `File.Exists`, you could just do in response to an exception.

Comment: you can see such behaviour with all kinds of network filesystems although Win7 is rather extreme with how long the value is cached... with win2k8 I see this very seldomn while with Win7 it is rather "regular"... I suspect some MS filesystem dev could answer your question... to get some help on SO you need to describe your goal more clearly IMO...

Comment: @Cody: Note sure I'm following you here. It seems reasonable for File.Exists to return true if Directory.GetFiles() lists it, no?

Comment: @DavidEbbo in a perfect world yes... but no software is perfect and filesystem handling (esp. network shares) is rather complicated with several level of caching etc. - it might even depend on what type of server the network share resides (for example samba versus win2k3 versus win2k8 etc.).

Comment: @Yahia the goal is to understand the behavior. Code that works on a local file system can break on a UNC because of this. Having a good understanding of the behavior can help write code that avoids issues.

Comment: @DavidEbbo as I wrote: the behaviour depends on several aspects ranging from client OS version to server OS version etc. I learned to NEVER assume local filesystem handling being comparable to network filesystem handling... IMO there is no general technique - a "correct/better" approach depends on your goal... what you describe as a goal is not "practical" IMO - what is the application-side functionality you want to achieve ? starting with this information there might several (other) ways to achieve the result you want...

Comment: @Yahia I added a NOTE section at the end which describes the concrete situation where this occurred. But I do think that gaining general understanding of the possible range of behavior is achievable (and useful) outside of this specific context.

Comment: does FileSystemWatcher provide improved return time? If it doesn't return, then you have a deeper protocol issue between you and the server. (i.e. we are plagued with NFS - and I do mean plagued).

Comment: @DavidEbbo the possible range is rather easy describes: from similar to local filesystem access to totally lagging with the worstcase being the need to unmount and remount that filesystem to solve some caching issues... it really depends on how well client and server code work together, the security setup, how well the protocol is implemented on both sides and whetever networking aspects (like latency, firewalls etc.) influences the behaviour... that's at least my experience with network filesystems...

Comment: @Yahia See answer below. It turns out it is not caused by random lag, but by a documented existence caching feature. And I'm sure you're right that there are many other factors at play. But this completely explains this specific 5 second delay.

Comment: @DavidEbbo already upvoted :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

David,
The redirector implements a negative "File Not Found" cache which prevents a client from flooding a server with file not found requests. The default cache time is 5 seconds but you can modify the FileNotFoundCacheLifetime registry value to control the cache or disable it by setting this value to 0.

Details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: Yep, that's it indeed! Setting this FileNotFoundCacheLifetime value to 0 removes that condition. Of course that may have negative perf implication on the system, so it may not be a smart thing to do. But I was mostly looking for something that explains the behavior, and this does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple levels of caching in network code. This could slow down the time the file existence finally shows up.

A solution would be not to use file shares but create a simple client/server architecture where the server returns the file existence from the local file system. That should really speed up item detection times.

My guess would be that if you tried to open the file even if File.Exists says it doesn't exist yet it should be opened correctly so you can use the server existence information. If that won't work you can simply add a download option to the server/client architecture.

Comment: Indeed, the file can be opened. See other answer; it turns out to be caused by a documented existence caching feature.

Answer (score 1):

Once I knew about the "File Not Found" cache, I was able to get around the problem by using a `FileInfo` object, which implements a `Refresh()` method.  Your code could do this instead:

```
FileInfo testFile = new FileInfo("test/test2/myfile");
Console.WriteLine("Exists (should be false): " + testFile .Exists);
Directory.Move("test/subdir/test", "test/test2");
testFile.Refresh();

// the FileInfo object should now be refreshed, and a second call to Exists will return a valid value
if (testFile.Exists)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I've just tried: Using FileInfo.Exists vs. File.Exists doesn't make any difference, even with Refresh().